# PHP if else statement issue with !=

Tags: php, session, if-statement

i cant figure out what is the mistake.

```
    if((!isset($_SESSION['user_username'])) || (!isset($_SESSION['user_role']))){
       header("location:index.php");
    }elseif( $_SESSION['user_role'] != "admin" || $_SESSION['user_role'] != "superadmin" ){
       header("location: noaccess.php");
    }
```

This is my code.... Even if i log in with admin user *(user_role=admin)*, it is redirecting to noaccess.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your mistake is in the `OR` (`||`) in the second statement.

```
if((!isset($_SESSION['user_username'])) || (!isset($_SESSION['user_role']))){
       header("location:index.php");
}elseif( $_SESSION['user_role'] != "admin" && $_SESSION['user_role'] != "superadmin" ){
       header("location: noaccess.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User @mariobgr has the right answer, you just need to swap the `||` for a `&&` on the second if statement. When you say something like `if($a || $b)` what you are really saying is "one of these things needs to be true" or "if $a is true, or $b is true then this statement is true". Your problem is that the way you are doing your statement will always return true. The role can't be both `admin` and `superAdmin`. For a little more explanation of why let's go through an example

So, `$role = 'admin';`. So the if statement says `if($role != 'admin')` which is false, because it is 'admin'. But the second part says `if($role != 'superAdmin')` which is true. So the `if` statement is true, because the second part is true. The opposite is true if `$role = 'superAdmin';`. The first part of the `if` is true and so the `if` statement is true because at least one of the statements is true.

If you switch the `||` to a `&&`, now both things need to be true in order for the `if` statement to evaluate to true. If `$role = 'admin';` the first part is false so the `if` statement is evaluated to false. If `$role = 'superAdmin';`, the second part is false meaning the `if` is false. The only way for the if statement to evaluate to true is if you are not `admin` `&&` you are not `superAdmin`.